# ObjectAttributes instance returned from the OPC .NET server is incorrectly identifying the IsCollectingHistory property as false

Tags: c#, opc

I am using the Xi interface to retrieve data from an OPC .NET server. The issue that I am having though is that the server seems to be incorrectly identifying a parameter as not being historized.

Even though all the information from DeltaV indicates that the corresponding parameter for the ObjectAttributes object returned from the server should indicate that it is collecting history, the IsCollectingHistory property actually indicates that it is false.

History collection is enabled:

[image: Historian Enabled]

The parameter in question is in the history collection:

[image: History Collection]

I won't include the screenshot but I can also open the historical trend for that parameter. But as you can see below, when I inspect the retrieved object while debugging, it says that it is not being historized.

[image: Debugging]

Here is some of the code that I am using:

```
FindCriteria criteria = createCriteria(path, false);
List<Parameter> parameters = new List<Parameter>();
IEnumerable<ObjectAttributes> enumerableObject;
int i = 0;
try 
{ 
    enumerableObject = iContext.FindObjects(criteria, 50); 
}
catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException)
{
    //This error is thrown when no data is returned.
    return null;
}
```

A few lines down, I then do some object initialization for my Parameter object, assigning it the properteries from the object that was received from the server. It is not shown below but I then add my Parameter object to a collection if it is being historized. It never gets added to the collection because the IsCollectingHistory property is always false.

```
enumerableObject = enumerableObject.Skip(1);
foreach (ObjectAttributes oa in enumerableObject)
{
    Parameter _parameter = new Parameter
    {
        IsHistorized = oa.IsCollectingHistory,
        IsLeaf = oa.IsLeaf
    };
    //...
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

**Edit:**

After trying MotteAndBailey's answer, an error is thrown at the call to AddNewDataObjectToDataJournalList. The message associated with it is "The OPC HDA Create Browse failed".

Below is a screenshot of the error in a message box when using HDAprobe:
[image: Create Browse failed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some info on properties in OPC.NET -

The Xi server wraps the OPCDA and OPCHDA servers.  The item properties (attributes) available on each server and the means of accessing them using Classic (DCOM) OPC vary considerably.

OPCDA

The OPCDA server provides a method for determining item properties:
IOPCItemProperties::GetItemProperties()

This call provides the client with a way to read all an item’s attribute values using the item ID (string path for the item in the Server’s address space) and propertyID. The Xi server uses this call when performing a FindObjects() call.  FindObjects() returns all the properties exposed by the OPCDA server for an item.

OPCHDA

The OPCHDA server has a method for determining item properties, but it requires the item handle not the ItemID/path:
IOPCHDA_SyncRead::ReadAttribute()

As a result, the FindObjects() call for an OPCHDA server through Xi only returns the item ID property.  The other attributes are set to defaults.  To determine what the actual values of the other properties are a user must add the item to a list and call ReadAttribute() on the specific property they wish to see.

In summary, the **OPCDA** server works pretty much like you would expect and returns the object properties in a single method call; however, the **OPCHDA** server requires an additional step to get all the object properties.

The sample code will produce an Xi Journal list with only the on-scan history items.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xi.Client.Base.API;
using Xi.Client.Base;
using Xi.Contracts;
using Xi.Contracts.Data;
using Xi.Contracts.Constants;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using Xi.Client.CommonDialogs;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleFindObjectsHDA
{
    public class DotNetSupport
    {
        IXiEndpointDiscovery iEndpointDiscovery;
        IXiContext iContext;
        IXiEndpointBase readEndpoint;

        ServiceEndpoint RMSvcEndpt;

        //the list of items the user is trying to read
        IXiDataJournalList iDataJournalList;

        public void GetSomeData()
        {
            //get a connection to an OPC.NET server
            if (Connect())
            {
                //we have to have a list to add a tag to and hold returned datasets
                if (CreateJournalList())
                {
                    //now use the list to add items and read their attributes - only "good" ones will be left on the list
                    ListAllHDAItemsOnScan();

                    if (iDataJournalList.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        //at this point we <should> have a DataJournalList containing only the HDA items on scan
                        //we can use the normal data read methods to get history for the items if we wish

                        //  <do some history thing here>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThere were no points on-scan in the historian");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\nPress <return> to exit program");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                ////clean up if we have open connections/contexts
                Cleanup();
            }

        }

        //we will use FindObjects to browse all the leaves in the HDA server, then add them one-by-one to a datalist
        //when we query their on-scan property and it is true we leave them on the list
        //...if not, we remove them (giving us a list of the good HDA points)
        void ListAllHDAItemsOnScan()
        {
            FindCriteria criteria = GetLeafCriteria(); 
            IEnumerable<ObjectAttributes> enumerableObject;

            try
            {
                //ask the server for a list of leaves...up to 50 max returned in this call
                enumerableObject = iContext.FindObjects(criteria, 50);

                //for each string itemID: add it to the list, read the attribute, and remove it from the list if not on-scan
                foreach (ObjectAttributes oa in enumerableObject)
                {
                    //we do not have to commit this because we have indicated the operation is NOT prep-only
                    Console.WriteLine("Adding OPCHDA item {0}.", oa.InstanceId.LocalId);
                    IXiHistoricalDataObject ixObject = iDataJournalList.AddNewDataObjectToDataJournalList(oa.InstanceId, false);   

                    //we are getting the CURRENT (from NOW -to- NOW) item status
                    FilterCriterion fc1 = GetFilterCriteriaDateTime(DateTime.Now); 

                    //tell the server what property (attribute) we want to read
                    List<TypeId> lstp = new List<TypeId>();
                    TypeId typeit = new TypeId("", "", DVServerAttributes.DELTAV_DVCH_ON_SCAN.ToString());
                    lstp.Add(typeit);

                    //read the property from the server
                    iDataJournalList.ReadJournalDataProperties(fc1, fc1, ixObject, lstp);

                    //find the current item and check it for "on-scan"
                    if (ixObject != null)
                    {
                        if (ixObject.PropertyValues.First().PropertyValues.UintValues.First() == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("OPCHDA item {0} is on-scan.\n", oa.InstanceId.LocalId);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (ixObject.PrepForRemove())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("OPCHDA item {0} is not on-scan. Removing item.\n", oa.InstanceId.LocalId);
                                iDataJournalList.CommitRemoveableElements();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception in FindObjects(). The exception is:{0}\n", ex.Message);
            }

        }


        //create a filtercriterion for a specific date time - this is an EQUAL (not > or <) comparison operator
        public FilterCriterion GetFilterCriteriaDateTime(DateTime dtChosenTime)
        {
            //simple timestamp filter which is used by the read call
            FilterCriterion filterCriterion = null;

            // this is a timestamp
            string filterOperand = FilterOperandNames.Timestamp;

            //make the given time with UTC/Local set to local time just to be sure
            DateTime dtTmp1 = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dtChosenTime, DateTimeKind.Local);
            object comparisonValue = dtTmp1;

            //timestamp equal to this one 
            uint oper = FilterOperator.Equal;

            //create the filter
            filterCriterion = new FilterCriterion()
            {
                OperandName = filterOperand,
                Operator = oper,
                ComparisonValue = comparisonValue,
            };

            return filterCriterion;
        }

        //create a filtercriterion for leaves (OPCHDA items)
        public FilterCriterion GetLeafFilterCriterion()
        {
            //simple filter for leaves 
            FilterCriterion filterCriterion = null;

            // what this criterion applies to
            string filterOperand = FilterOperandNames.BranchOrLeaf;

            //Must equal "LEAF" to match
            uint oper = FilterOperator.Equal;

            //create the filter
            filterCriterion = new FilterCriterion()
            {
                OperandName = filterOperand,
                Operator = oper,
                ComparisonValue = "LEAF",
            };

            return filterCriterion;
        }

        //set up the FindCriteria search of the server  
        public FindCriteria GetLeafCriteria()
        {
            FindCriteria findCriteria = null;
            findCriteria = new FindCriteria();

            //our browse starts at the root - NULL means "continue browsing from where you are"
            findCriteria.StartingPath = new ObjectPath("//", "HDA");

            //a list of OR-ed filter criteria (we have only one)
            ORedFilters orthefilters = new ORedFilters();

            //the FilterCriteria list (there is only one criterion)
            orthefilters.FilterCriteria = new List<FilterCriterion>();
            orthefilters.FilterCriteria.Add(GetLeafFilterCriterion());  //we want leaves

            //add our OR-ed filter to the filterset filters list (whew!)
            findCriteria.FilterSet = new FilterSet();
            findCriteria.FilterSet.Filters = new List<ORedFilters>();
            findCriteria.FilterSet.Filters.Add(orthefilters);

            return findCriteria;
        }


        //connect to the OPC.NET server and get a read endpoint
        public bool Connect()
        {
            //set this to point to your OPC.Net server
            string serverUrl = "http://localhost:58080/XiServices/ServerDiscovery";

            bool bReturnVal = false;

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting Endpoint Discovery from server:\n{0}\n", serverUrl);

                //This class is used to locate a server and obtain its list of ServiceEndpoints.
                iEndpointDiscovery = new XiEndpointDiscovery(serverUrl) as IXiEndpointDiscovery;

                //we have the server...now check for endpoints
                //there should always be TCP endpoints for a DeltaV OPC.NET server so we do not search HTTP and Named Pipes to find one
                //and we do not consider choosing the fastest option between the three (TCP/HTTP/NamedPipes). We just use the TCP/IP one.

                // GetServiceEndpointsByBinding searches the list of endpoints on the XiEndpointDiscovery connection with the specified contractType and binding type.
                // We use the ResourceManagement endpoint to find the the other open endpoints on the server (some might be disabled)
                IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint> resourceEndpoints = iEndpointDiscovery.GetServiceEndpointsByBinding(typeof(IResourceManagement).Name, typeof(System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding));

                //use the first (probably only) resource endpoint for TCP/IP to open a context between client and server
                if ((resourceEndpoints != null) && (resourceEndpoints.Count() > 0))
                {

                    var serviceEndpoints = resourceEndpoints as IList<ServiceEndpoint> ?? resourceEndpoints.ToList();


                    //pick the first RM endpoint we found
                    RMSvcEndpt = ((IList<ServiceEndpoint>)serviceEndpoints).First();

                    //Open the Context using the RM endpoint and some other values including timeout, what we want to read (HDA), and the GUID for this context
                    Console.WriteLine("Opening Client Context with Initiate\n");
                    iContext = XiContext.Initiate(RMSvcEndpt,
                                                        iEndpointDiscovery.ServerEntry,
                                                        300000,
                                                        (uint)ContextOptions.EnableJournalDataAccess,   //HDA
                                                        (uint)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID,
                                                        Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

                    if (iContext != null)
                    {

                        //find a read endpoint using the XiEndpointDiscovery connection
                        IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint> readseps = iEndpointDiscovery.GetServiceEndpointsByBinding(typeof(IRead).Name, RMSvcEndpt.Binding.GetType());

                        //if we found at least one read endpoint, connect the context to it
                        readEndpoint = null;
                        if (readseps != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Adding Read endpoint to Context\n");
                            ServiceEndpoint sep = readseps.ElementAt<ServiceEndpoint>(0);
                            readEndpoint = iContext.OpenEndpoint(sep, 30000, new TimeSpan(5000));

                            if (readEndpoint != null)
                            {
                                bReturnVal = true;        //everything went OK
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Unable to add Read endpoint to Context\n");
                                bReturnVal = false;        //failed
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Unable to open Client Context\n");
                        bReturnVal = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                bReturnVal = false;
            }

            return (bReturnVal);
        }


        public bool CreateJournalList()
        {
            bool retval = false;

            try
            {
                //create a new list of HDA objects for this read
                //                                             update  buffer  
                //                                             rate    rate   filterset(not used here)
                iDataJournalList = iContext.NewDataJournalList(1000,   1000,  null);

                if (iDataJournalList != null)
                {
                    //we need to add the list to a read endpoint to give it data access
                    iDataJournalList.AddListToEndpoint(readEndpoint);

                    //enable the list so we can connect the items we add to it and read data
                    iDataJournalList.EnableListUpdating(true);

                    retval = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                retval = false;
            }

            return retval;
        }


        public void Cleanup()
        {
            if (iContext != null)
            {
                iContext.Dispose();
            }

        }

    } //class DotNetSupport
}

namespace ConsoleFindObjectsHDA
{
    public class DVServerAttributes
    {
        //some DeltaV-specific OPCHDA attributes
        public static uint DELTAV_DESC               = 2147483650;
        public static uint DELTAV_ENG_UNITS          = 2147483651;
        public static uint DELTAV_EU100              = 2147483666;
        public static uint DELTAV_EU0                = 2147483667;
        public static uint DELTAV_DVCH_LAST_DOWNLOAD = 2147483682;
        public static uint DELTAV_DVCH_ON_SCAN       = 2147483683;
        public static uint DELTAV_NAMED_SET          = 2147483698;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will implement it in my code tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I apologize for taking so long to get back to you. Unfortunately, I am still having some issues. So I copied and pasted your code and there is an error thrown at the iContext.FindObjects call. The message associated with error is "OPC HDA CreateBrowse() failed". Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, holidays got in the way of looking at this. One way to check out whether the OPCHDA server is accepting connections and allowing browsing is to use the DeltaV utility "HDAProbe" locally on the DV workstation.  Connect to the local server, do an "add items", "Browse", and then "New Browser".  You should see HDA items in the dialog window.  If this succeeds you can close HDAProbe and try the OPC.NET generic client. Connect it up, add a data journal list, enable it, and try to add some items.  The add dialog is actually a browsing dialog.

Comment: Hmm ... When I select "New Browser", I get the same error as described when I was running your code. Everything else seems to be fine with the history collection. I am able able to view a trend in process history view.

Comment: HDAProbe will give an error 0xE23E0017 doing a "New Browser" if there are not enough HDA client licenses for the additional connection.  The server allows one free client connection, but more than that require a license or an Integrator dongle.  It is possible that some other process has used the license and is holding on to its connection (and the license).  If you are getting a different error code, I'll take a look at it if you post it.

Comment: The error message and error code are attached. I am using an Integrator dongle. It must be something that I am not doing because I am using a different virtual machine now and having the same issue.

Comment: Not sure what to make of it - if HDAProbe can connect and get status from the server you've connected up to it OK with DCOM.  Not sure why browsing would be the problem.  Does the Windows Application log on the server machine have any complaints?

Comment: Yeah, there is something in the Windows Application log but it doesn't really provide any additional information: "DeltaV OPC HDA Server failed to create the DeltaV Continuous Historian tag selector in CreateBrowser() => InitBrowser().
-2147220982 (0x8004020A)"

Comment: Take a look at this [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhx38p6epetcerw/HDABrowse.png?dl=0). Is there anything else I need to do here? I have tried setting this up with the station configured as a DeltaV Continuous Historian and also tried Advanced Continuous Historian. I get the same result. I also seem to have [two](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hfddietmhhx68mv/OPCHDAsvr.png?dl=0) options when selecting an HDA server --- don't know why. But in any case I have tried both of these selections as well.

Comment: Problem solved. It wasn't an issue with the code suggested by @MotteAndBailey. It was a weird quirk with DeltaV. I removed the area from the historian, added a new module (no history collection in this module), downloaded the module, added the area back to the historian, downloaded the historian, and restarted the computer. It started working after that.